# Quicksight calculated field

Tags: parameters, calculated-field, amazon-quicksight

Im trying to created a calculated field
where sum and max functions are used.
Sum({$<DateID =  {$(=max(DateID))}>}  InServiceDays)
This above statement means i want sum of inservicedays where dateid=max(dateid)
but how to make this thing possible using calculated field or parameters in quicksight.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have field called `dateID` and you want to sum `{InServiceDays}` for rows whose `dateID` is the maximum.

This can be expressed using the following calculated field in QuickSight

```
sumIf({inServiceDays}, DateID = maxOver(dateID,[], PRE_AGG))
```

Comment: I want to ask one more thing here-
Sum($(vSetYTD) ResidentDays) this calculated field is doing sum of "residentDays' while setting YTD function(This expression is used in qlik sense/qlikview.)
Now in quicksight how to set a similar YTD function so that if I have given a filter/control of date(Year).My YTD changes automatically to that year.
Example 2021 YTD of sum(residentdays)=80%
after selecting the year as 2020 I get YTD of 2020 year.
Looking for your positive response